# Is there community interest in an SE gardening blog?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

As we go through the year there will be topics that are borderline for our main Q&A site, but still have a lot of value to the gardening community at large and will help bring more traffic and questions to the site.

So I would like to propose [A gardening blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/). This would provide us with a place to have extended articles on things like seasonal planting, our home gardens or other things that are going on in the gardening world. Things that are probably off topic, or just too darn localized or subjective would be fair game for an entire well researched or well documented article.

Comment: @Tea. at this point it might be best to just gauge interest and do a separate post asking for contributers. Else I am ok if people want to volunteer here.

Comment: If this does come to fruition, I'd be willing to commit to at least one blog post a month.  I am kept busy by our workload here, and I do blog on the blog.serverfault.com site already, but gardening is a side passion of mine.  We've even discussed having a small indoor garden here at the StackExchange offices, which might make an interesting subject for a blog series.

Comment: @PeterGrace that's awesome. I've had a thought of asking SE to do an office garden at one point just to promo the site and generate some questions. Didn't know anyone would be interested. That would be awesome.

Comment: I would also be willing to help. I could either help with posts as a second contributor (e.g. drafts, proofing, taking pictures) or write posts myself but less than once a month.

Answer (score 7):

I think it would have a lot of value.

If we start a separate discussion to see who might be the contributors, I'll put my name forward.

Wax are you offering to coordinate it? the link talks about this being essential (coordinating doesn't commit you to writing articles).

Comment: I would be willing to coordinate and maybe write an article here and there. I don't think I can commit to actually doing anything regularly, but I can definitely try to coordinate.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Proposed format...

Aim for a least one post per month. Could draw inspiration from either of the following:

1. Per wax eagle, things "that are probably off topic, or just too darn localized or subjective" which can be described in a well researched blog post.
2. Recurrent themes covered by several questions (e.g. "things to grow in an office" or  "bugs that appear on your tomatoes");
3. Things to do in north hemisphere this month (e.g. "sowing winter legumes") but of course there are many other blogs that do this, so should focus on a topic that has appeared on the gardening SE;
4. Things to do in south hemisphere this month (e.g. "planting autumn salads");
5. Gardening SE contributor's garden profile (e.g. they did a podcast of the Sherlock guy on the DIY SE so something like that but about an individual's garden/gardening experience and how the Gardening SE fits in to their gardening with pictures of favourite plants/patches/tools);
6. Summary of meta discussions (possibly that happened over more than one thread here) of interest to the general contributors at gardening SE, including "news style" items (e.g. "seed saving chat room launched for Gardening SE").

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it sounds like a good idea. We'd need to hammer out details like whether we have any tighter focus or theme than just "gardening & landscaping" and a schedule.

I'd be willing to contribute a post a month.

Answer (score 3):

I like the suggestions we've had thus far in Lisa's post above and [Peter's post](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/a/332/109) in a different question.

I'd be willing to contribute about a post a month.